# ¿Cómo solucionar el siguiente error? "Se detectó un posible valor Request.Path peligroso en el cliente "

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2016, cloud

tengo un proyecto en visual studio, pero necesito utilizar un servicio en la nube para insertar **"Tables, Blobs y Colas"**, esa parte si me funciona muy bien... pero también necesito insertar datos a una tabla de sql server 2016, al compilarlo todo va bien, pero cuando ingreso los datos en los txt y doy click en el botón de **Guardar** me manda el siguiente error **Se detectó un posible valor Request.Path peligroso en el cliente**, ¿Qué podría ser?

Gracias de atemano!

Comment: Esto es ASP.NET Webforms? Que version de .NET? Si es asi... haces un postback y te da dicho error? Estas ingresando un texto con alguno de estos caracteres <,>,*,%,&,:,\,?

Answer (score 0):

Deshabilita la característica de validación de solicitudes ASP.NET. Para hacerlo, en el archivo .aspx de la página web, establece la configuración Page ValidateRequest así:

```
<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false"%>
```

Como alternativa, en el archivo Web.config de la aplicación web, establece el atributo `validateRequest` de la sección `<pages/>` en false así:

```
<configuration> <system.web> <pages validateRequest="false" /> </system.web> </configuration>
```

Comment: Ya intente de esa manera, pero no me funcionó:(

Answer (score 0):

En GX X U4 con K2B v7.1 sobre W10 64 y asp .NET 4.8 mas SQL Server Express 2008R2,  me daba este error lo cual solucione con
1º agregar en programas y características ASP .net 2.0 a 3.5
2º y luego en directorio de la aplicación CSharp/web editar la WEB config, agregando en
<system.web>
estas dos lineas...

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="3.5" />
<pages validateRequest="false" />
```

y funcionó todo perfecto....